# compile only objects by default with makefile

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile to compile and generate only object files from the source code. I have this so far:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

when I call it, it prints:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Obviously I am making a mistake, but I don't know which one, because I am seeing in the [GNU make documentation page](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) a very similar example.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: By convention, `CC` is a C compiler. `CXX` is the C++ compiler.  And `CXXFLAGS` are the flags.

Comment: Perhaps  `wildcard *.h` should be `wildcard *.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace: `SOURCES=$(wildcard *.h)` with `SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)`

and:

```
$(OBJECTS):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

with:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This means that each `{file}.o` is depend on existence of `{file}.cpp`.

Comment: Also, as mentioned by William Pursell, for C++, better use `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` rather than `CC` and `CFLAGS`.